# DWM Thumbnail of HWND to Bitmap

Tags: c#, graphics, screenshot, pascal, dwm

I have been thrashing my head against a wall with this.  I am trying to create screen-shot based programme (where the programme(hwnd) is *not* the top-most window ).  I need to process the thumbnail and cannot manage to get a dwm derived thumbnail image into a bitmap.  I think that I am missing something heart-breakingly basic.

The two crucial bits of code are

```
    res:=dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(wnd,DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION,@fForceIconic,Sizeof(fb));
if res<>s_OK then
begin
     label1.Caption:='Force Iconic Error :'+Inttostr(Res);
end;
res:=dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(wnd,DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP,@fHasIconicBitmap,Sizeof(fb));`enter code here`
```

All that seems to accomplish is to break the target window's thumbnail (it displays in alt-tab as the 'loading' circle'

I also have message procedures to respond the the messages

```
procedure WMDwmsendiconicthumbnail(var Message: TMessage); message WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL;
procedure WMDwmsendiconiclivepreviewbitmap(var Message: TMessage);message WM_DWMSENDICONICLIVEPREVIEWBITMAP;
```

These message procedures are never called - probably because I have never sent the target hwnd any kind of message with my own application's HWND.  I can't find any working examples of code that meets my need.  I can't even find any explanation of what I really need to do.

Any language is fine - This is an API problem rather than a language specific issue.  Could somebody please point in the right direction.

(nb : canvas capture or printwindow are not suitable as the target hwnd is using openGL - Likewise simply capturing the whole monitor won't work as my application is intended to work as a picture-in-picture programme that is similar to OnTopReplica)

Comment: Delphi or Lazarus? Lazarus by default only handles the messages it knows (there is wiki article somewhere for that)

Comment: Delphi.  However I have sinced learned that what I want to do is actually impossible - now. There was hack using undocumented api calls in vista - but they no longer work.  So I am having to go full-tilt on this and use dll injection.  As you can imagine this is difficult but it is the proverbial final solution to my current project and also another broader one (I want an all-inclusive window Resizer - with filtering & mouse/kbrd pass through)  primarily so that I can run older and indy games with fixed resolutions in a window of any size.  Also upscaling 1080p games to fill my 4k monitor.